# Help understanding a strong induction example in Bona's "A walk through Combinatorics"

Tags: combinatorics, induction

[Part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWs9J.png)

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt5mS.png)

Please refer to the images to see the example.

I do not understand how substituting a_n = (2^n) − 1
into the recurrence relation

a_n+1 =a_0 +···+a_n +n+1=(2^0 −1)+···+(2^n −1)+n+1

results in the sum 1+2+4+···+2^n = 2^(n+1) −1.

I see that the partial sums to 1 + 2 + 4 + ... coincide with the terms in the recurrence relation, but I do not understand how one goes from substituting a_n into each term of the recurrence relation a_n+1 to deriving the "explicit formula for n+1". I hope someone can help me bridge this gap in my understanding.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By a direct derivation :
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} (2^{k}-1) + n+1 &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{k} -(n+1) + n+1\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{k}
\end{align*}

Now this is a standard geometric sum but let's compute it anyway
\begin{align*}
S_n &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{k}\\
&= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} 2^{k} - 2^{n+1}\\
&= 1 + 2 \sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{k} - 2^{n+1}\\
&= 2 S_n + 1 - 2^{n+1}
\end{align*}
Solving for $S_n$ gives $S_n=2^{n+1}-1$ as desired.